# Why ip_forward_use_pmtu added in the result of sysctl in linux server

Tags: linux, kernel, ipv4, sysctl

So I did an OS version-up in a linux server, and was seeing if any setting has been changed.
And when I typed "sysctl -a | grep "net.ipv4.ip_forward"
The following line was added,

net.ipv4.ip_forward_use_pmtu = 0

I know that this is because this parameter is in /proc/sys.
But I think if the result of sysctl before upload did not show this line, it was not in /proc/sys before as well, right ?
I know that 0 means " this setting is not applied...So basically it does not do anything.
But why this line is added.

The question is

**Is there any possible reason that can add this line?**

Thank you, ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Even the question itself "added in the result of sysctl in linux server" is wrong here.

`sysctl` in the way you invoked it, lists all the entries.
`grep` which you used to filter those entries "selects" matching texts, if you'd run `grep foo` against the list:

- foo
- foobar

both items would be matched. That's exactly what you see but the only difference is instead of "foo" you have "net.ipv4.ip_forward".

Using `--color` shows that clearly:

[image]

Pay attention to the use of `fgrep` instead of `grep` because people tend to forget that `grep` interprets some characters as regular expressions, and the dot `.` means *any character*, which might also lead to unexpected matches.